# Difference between OpenReadAsync and DownloadFromStreamAsync functions of CloudBlockBlob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

What is the difference between `OpenReadAsync` and `DownloadToStreamAsync` functions of `CloudBlockBlob` in the Azure blob storage? Searched in google but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both OpenReadAsync and DownloadToStreamAsync could initiate an asynchronous operation for you to retrieve the blob stream.
Based on my testing, you could have a better understanding of them by the following sections:

#### Basic Concepts

DownloadToStreamAsync：Initiates an asynchronous operation to download the contents of a blob to a stream.

OpenReadAsync：Initiates an asynchronous operation to download the contents of a blob to a stream.

#### Usage

a) DownloadToStreamAsync

Sample Code:

```html
using (var fs = new FileStream(<yourLocalFilePath>, FileMode.Create))
{
    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(fs);
}
```

b) OpenReadAsync

Sample Code:

```html
//Set buffer for reading from a blob stream, the default value is 4MB.
blob.StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes=10*1024*1024; //10MB
using (var blobStream = await blob.OpenReadAsync())
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create))
    {   
       await blobStream.CopyToAsync(fs);
    }
}
```

#### Capturing Network requests via Fiddler

a) DownloadToStreamAsync

[image]
[image]
 
b) OpenReadAsync

[image]
[image]

According to the above, DownloadToStreamAsync just sends one get request for retrieving blob stream, while OpenReadAsync sends more than one request to retrieving blob stream based on the “Blob.StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes” you have set or by default value.

Comment: Fantastic answer. This is the only place I found this documented and it would explain issues with larger files.

Comment: issues with larger files?

Comment: How does DownloadToStreamAsync deal with the buffer memory though?

Answer (score 6):

The difference between `DownloadToStreamAsync` and `OpenReadAsync` is that `DownloadToStreamAsync` will download the contents of the blob to the stream before returning, but `OpenReadAsync` will not trigger a download until the stream is consumed.

For example, if using this to return a file stream from an ASP.NET core service, you should use `OpenReadAsync` and not `DownloadToStreamAsync`:

Example with `DownloadToStreamAsync` (not recommended in this case):

```csharp
Stream target = new MemoryStream(); // Could be FileStream
await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(target); // Returns when streaming (downloading) is finished. This requires the whole blob to be kept in memory before returning!
_logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, $"DownloadToStreamAsync: Length: {target.Length} Position: {target.Position}"); // Output: DownloadToStreamAsync: Length: 517000 Position: 517000
target.Position = 0; // Rewind before returning Stream:
return File(target, contentType: blob.Properties.ContentType, fileDownloadName: blob.Name, lastModified: blob.Properties.LastModified, entityTag: null);
```

Example with `OpenReadAsync` (recommended in this case):

```csharp
// Do NOT put the stream in a using (or close it), as this will close the stream before ASP.NET finish consuming it.
Stream blobStream = await blob.OpenReadAsync(); // Returns when the stream has been opened
_logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, $"OpenReadAsync: Length: {blobStream.Length} Position: {blobStream.Position}"); // Output: OpenReadAsync: Length: 517000 Position: 0
return File(blobStream, contentType: blob.Properties.ContentType, fileDownloadName: blob.Name, lastModified: blob.Properties.LastModified, entityTag: null);
```

Comment: Sorry, but why it's not recommended? What could go wrong?

Comment: DownloadToStreamAsync will load the whole blob into memory and only after that the stream will return. As OpenReadAsync will only read chunks and pass that down. So if I understood it correctly. OpenReadAsync is well fitted for scenarios where read speed can differ and/or memory should be saved.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from a member of Microsoft Azure ([here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/22022#issuecomment-870054035)):

> The difference between `DownloadStreamingAsync` and `OpenReadAsync` is
> that the former gives you a network stream (wrapped with few layers
> but effectively think about it as network stream) which holds on to
> single connection, the later on the other hand fetches payload in
> chunks and buffers issuing multiple requests to fetch content. Picking
> one over the other one depends on the scenario, i.e. if the consuming
> code is fast and you have good broad network link to storage account
> then former might be better choice as you avoid multiple req-res
> exchanges but if the consumer is slow then later might be a good idea
> as it releases a connection back to the pool right after reading and
> buffering next chunk. We recommend to perf test your app with both to
> reveal which is best choice if it's not obvious.

Answer (score -2):

OpenReadAsync returns a `Task<Stream>` and you use it with an await.

sample test method

```
CloudBlobContainer container = GetRandomContainerReference();
            try
            {
                await container.CreateAsync();

                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob1");
                using (MemoryStream wholeBlob = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                {
                    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(wholeBlob);
                }

                using (MemoryStream wholeBlob = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                {
                    using (var blobStream = await blob.OpenReadAsync())
                    {
                        await TestHelper.AssertStreamsAreEqualAsync(wholeBlob, blobStream);
                    }
                }
            }
```

DownloadToStreamAsync  is a virtual (can be overridden) method  returning a task and takes stream object as input.

sample usage.

```
await blog.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
```