# Random Access Stream Azure Block Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to create a stream object directly to Azure Blob or Azure Block Storage Blob.

IE

```
var s = new AzureStream(blockObject)
ms.CopyTo(s);
s.position = 200;
ms.CopyTo(s);
s.Read...
```

This would allow for some awesome interactions such as storing database Indices in azure blob and not needing to pull them local.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question, but you can read a range of bytes from a blob. When using the REST API directly, you can specify the bytes you want to read in either the `Range` or `x-ms-range` header.

When using C# SDK, You can use [`DownloadRangeToStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/jj732061(v%3Dazure.10)) method, something like:

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            long offset = 200;
            long bytesToRead = 1024;
            blob.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, offset, bytesToRead);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is, "can I use Streams with Azure Blobs", in order to avoid the need to hold the entire size of the blob in memory at any point in time, then the answer is absolutely yes.

For example, when reading block blobs, as per this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38889055), blobs can be accessed as a stream handle with methods such as `CloudBlob.OpenReadAsync`. The default buffer size is 4MB, but can be adjusted via properties like [StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/jj732675(v%3Dazure.10)). Here we copy the blob stream to another open, output stream:

```
using (var stream = await myBlockBlob.OpenReadAsync(cancellationToken))
{
    await stream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
}
```

Similar, you can [write a stream](https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/azure-storage/basic-operations) directly into Blob Storage:

```
 await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(streamToSave, cancellationToken);
```